# Hide outbound proxy configuration from Virtual machines

Tags: routing, proxy, vmware-vsphere

We are running some VMs in a Vmware network such that we have to use an outbound proxy set as environment variable inside the machines , so that they can connect to the internet to download packages and do other stuff , this can be problematic for those applications running inside the machines that do not use environment variables for outbound proxy configurations.And they need to be configured in some special way to use the outbound proxy.

I wonder if there is a way that the VM can use the outbound proxy without knowing that it is using an outbound proxy to connect to the internet , is there a way to make the VM believe that it is not using an outbound proxy and its directly connected to the internet , while behind the scenes it is connecting through outbound proxy.

Is there something that can be done at VMware Vsphere level.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at the VMware level, but you may be looking for a "transparent proxy"

Comment: Do u mean some linux box with ip maqurading?

Comment: not specifically ip masquerading, but firewall intercepting traffic and forcing it into a proxy. Also called "inline proxy".